# Как сделать что бы postgresql принимала в поле TIMESTAMPTZ дату-время-зону и не изменяла ее, а сохраняла как есть?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

Таблица:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test
    (
        id         SERIAL4 PRIMARY KEY,
        title      VARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL,
        body       TEXT                  NOT NULL,
        user_id    INT                   NOT NULL,
        is_deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
        created_at TIMESTAMPTZ           NOT NULL,
        updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ           NOT NULL
    );
```

Например в поле TIMESTAMPTZ я сохраняю '2022-11-14 18:01:01+04', но БД записывает
'2022-11-14 14:01:01.000000 +00:00'. Другое время, добавление ненужных микросекунд и отсутствие временной зоны.
То же самое если записываю в таком формате '2022-11-14 18:01:01+04:00',
записывается '2022-11-14 14:01:01.000000 +00:00'.

Запрос в БД, опустил ненужные поля:

```
insert into public.test (created_at) values
('2022-11-14 18:01:01+04');
```

Походу PyCharm тупит, PgAdmin отображает нормально (как сохраняю), но
когда смотрю или делаю запрос на просмотр через PyCharm '2022-11-14 14:01:01.000000 +00:00'

Comment: думается, вы не туда копаете. какие трудности вызывает у вас такое сохранение данных?

Comment: В таблице значение всегда хранится в UTC. Вообще-то... *Запрос в БД* В данном случае спецификацию, конечно, определит структура, но лучше использовать `.. VALUES (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2022-11-14 18:01:01+04')`.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь про TimeZone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188151/how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc  Ещё можно создать поле так 
    created_at timestamp without time zone not null,